# Alternative to a utility class for extension methods in C#?

Tags: c#, static, extension-method

I understand that in OOP languages like C#, it is generally viewed as bad practice to create utility classes, and it's preferable to put methods in the classes in which they will be used.

To that end, I wanted to create a `transpose()` extension method for `double[,]` types; however, it told me that extension methods must be declared in non-generic static classes. The problem is that the class that's supposed to utilize the method is meant to be instantiated.

Should I create a static `Math` class (I do have other methods I could put in it), or should I just make it a regular function rather than a static function?

(The class it's in is a `neuralNetwork` class, and it doesn't really make sense to create a static class and have `neuralNetwork` inherit from it).

Comment: eh? Extension methods are invoked from instances, even if they're declared in a static class. Could you clarify a little bit the problem you're encountering, or options you're considering?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Best Practices and Good Design are things you should strive to follow, but there's always an exception or valid reason to violate them.**

This is one of the necessary exceptions to "No Utility Classes". The importance of the class being a Non-Generic Static is deep in the guts of C#, this is how a class is able to find the extension methods at compile time (note: not a fully accurate explanation).  If you pop open the code of Entity Framework, you can see this in action against the various types of `IQueryable` getting extension methods like `ToList()`.

From a design standpoint, an Extension class is considered good design since it adheres to as many [SOLID Principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) as it can (Single Responsibility, Open-Closed, Interface Segregation and Dependency Inversion, if you squint a little) while still following the rules of the language (it must be Static and Non-Generic).